# Make a GET Request and receive parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httpwebrequest, chargify

I am working on a Ruby on Rails App.I have to make a GET request to following:

> https://[@subdomain].chargify.com/subscriptions/[@subscription.id].json

The response received is going to be json. I am trying to achieve this by making the GET request using the 'net/http' library of ruby and my code is as follows :

```
res = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('https://[@subdomain].chargify.com/subscriptions/[@subscription_id].json'))
```

But I am getting an error which is :

> bad URI(is not URI?):
>   https://[@subdomain].chargify.com/subscriptions/[@subscription_id].json

I am not sure where exactly am I making mistake with this. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I followed the instructions and now my code reads like this : @res = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("https://#{@subdomain}.chargify.com/subscriptions/#{@sub‌​scription_id}.json")) Now in my view when I do debug(@res) It is giving me this error: --- | <html> <head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center> <center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center> <hr><center>nginx/0.7.66</center> </body> </html> Any idea how do I resolve this issue ?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `#{@subdomain}` instead of `[@subdomain]`? That has to be inside of double quotes `"` in order to get interpolated properly.

Comment: like this - Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("https://#{@subdomain}.chargify.com/subscriptions/#{@subscription_id}.json"))

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. `#{...}` will evaluate the contents and convert it to a string, calling `.to_s` as required.

Answer (score 1):

By now you know that your error was that you didn't interpolate the string correctly. You should have specified #{@subdomain} rather than [@subdomain] and you need **double quotes** around the string

The problem that you now have is that **you need to tell the http connection to use ssl**. I use something like this ..

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
```

Comment: No I am not getting the json response like this or may be I am doing it wrong. Here is my code :

uri = URI.parse("https://#{@subdomain}.chargify.com/subscriptions/#{@subscription_id}.json")
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

      http.use_ssl = true
      @res = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

And here is the error I am getting now :

--- !ruby/object:Net::HTTP::Get 
body: 
body_stream: 
header: 
  accept: 
  - "*/*"
method: GET
path: /subscriptions/660668.json
request_has_body: false
response_has_body: true

Not sure now what is causing this ?

Comment: Silly question (sorry) but did you call @res.response.body ? It's a bit late here so my thinking is fuzzy so maybe that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The value of @subdomain needs to be passed using

   ```
   #{@subdomain}
   ```
2. The connection is ssl

   ```
   def net_http(uri)
   h = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
   h.use_ssl=true
           h
   end
   ```

Then

```
     request=net_http(URI.parse("https://#       {@subdomain}.chargify.com/subscriptions/#{@subscription_id}.json"))
```

To perform get actions

```
     request=net_http(URI.parse("https://#       {@subdomain}.chargify.com/subscriptions/#{@subscription_id}.json")).start do |http|
        http.get(URI.parse("whatever_url").path,{:params=>123})
        end
```